# How to create a Mootools Vertical Slider

Tags: mootools

Please anybody can suggest me a Mootools vertical news scroller same as www.cardomain.com activity listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution. How advanced is your moo fu?

Roll your own: Use or even extend Fx.Scroll. After adding items, scroll the container to top/bottom (depending on your design) with your Fx.Scroll instance.

Most activity scrollers "fake" their "real-time" activity, and load one set of activities which they remove from top and append to the end on the fly to give the real-time update feeling.